# Disable automatic sending of shared document notifications

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api

I have a google sheet file containing recordings; in particular, column A contains a URL that I want to share with recipients that I enter in columns B and C. I want to put these recipients in the editor of the corresponding URL but without sending a notification.

I try this code:

```
function partagerFichiers() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");
  let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  let fichierUrl, destinataireEd1, destinataireEd2, destinataireCom, destinataireLec;
  for (i=1;i<=data.length;i++) {
    if (data[i].length > 1 && data[i][0] !== "") { //on récupère la 1ère colonne
      fichierUrl = data[i][0];}
    if (data[i].length > 1 && data[i][2] !== "") {
      destinataireEd1 = data[i][2].split(";").map(function(item) { return item.trim(); });} //on récupère la 3ème colonne
    if (data[i].length > 1 && data[i][3] !== "") {
      destinataireEd2 = data[i][3].split(";").map(function(item) { return item.trim(); });} //on récupère la 4ème colonne

    try {
      let fichierId = fichierUrl.replace(/.*\/d\//, '').replace(/\/.*/, '');
      let fichier = DriveApp.getFileById(fichierId);
      destinataireEd1.forEach(function(mail) { fichier.addEditor(mail); });
      destinataireEd1.forEach(destinataireEd1 => {
      Drive.Permissions.create({ role: "writer", type: "user", emailAddress: destinataireEd1 }, fichier, { sendNotificationEmail: false });});
      destinataireEd2.forEach(function(mail) { fichier.addEditor(mail); });
    } catch (error) {
      Logger.log("Erreur lors de la récupération du fichier pour l'url: " + fichierUrl);
      Logger.log("Erreur :" + error.message);
    }
  }
}
```

But I get several errors : "Error: Drive is not defined" and "Error: Invalid argument: permission.value" (for the last one, I think it comes from the fact that I have no return address for certain records )

Thanks

Comment: Did you enable the Drive API in the cloud console?

Comment: @Cooper uh no, I admit I don't even really know what that means

Comment: It means that `Drive` is undefined in your project

Comment: So I can't use it without a Google account?

Comment: I don't think that you can run any google apps script without a google account

Comment: In this case if you wish to enable Drive API that you will have to make it a GCP Project.  Look in the gear section of your script editor

Comment: The script works if I remove the line 'Drive.Permissions.create({ role: "writer", type: "user", emailAddress: recipientEd1 }, file, { sendNotificationEmail: false });});'

Comment: There's a difference between having  a GCP project and having a google account

Comment: It looks like the [`file.addEditor(mail)`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file#addeditoremailaddress) method in your script accomplishes the same task as your `Drive.Permissions.create` *([which is one of the Drive API Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced) method)* by granting editor access to the specified email addresses, so there's no need to use this line of code. Also, just to confirm, your intention is to only share editor access for each file ID without sending email notifications, correct?

Comment: @SputnikDrunk2 Yes that's right: I want to share only editor access for each file ID without sending email notifications

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Suggestion

If you want to share files with recipients without them getting an email notification, you can do so by using the **[Advanced Drive Service Drive API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/drive)** for Google Apps Script. You are on the right track by using `Drive.Permissions.create`. In addition, I have tweaked your existing script to make it more readable and efficient, using fewer for loops and conditional if statements.

To begin, you will need to enable the Drive API Advanced **Services** in your Apps Script editor *(this fixes the `Error: Drive is not defined`)*, as shown below:

[image]

### Tweaked Script *[UPDATED]*

> **Note:** If you encounter an issue with your actual spreadsheet file with this sample script, it would be greatly appreciated if you could **provide a sample sheet** from your end so that we can better reproduce your setup.

```
function shareFiles() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Feuille 1");
  let data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  const dataToBeProcessed = data.map((row, i) => {
    return i != 0 && row.map(cell => {
      try {
        return new RegExp("d\/(.*)\/", "gm").exec(cell)[1]; //extract file ID from the link
      } catch {
        return cell.trim().split(";") //split email addresses for recipient 1 / recipient 2
      }
    })
  }).filter(x => x); //filter non-important values

  //Process sheet file data
  dataToBeProcessed.forEach(data => {

    let fileId = data[0];
    let setRole = 'reader'; //Set the role here.

    try {
      data[1].forEach(editor1Recipient => {
        editor1Recipient != '' && (setRole == 'writer' ? setAsWriter(setRole, editor1Recipient, fileId) : setAsReader(setRole, editor1Recipient, fileId), console.log(`Successfully shared file ID: (${fileId}) to ${editor1Recipient} with a "${setRole}" role.`))
      });

      data[2].forEach(editor2Recipient => {
        editor2Recipient != '' && (setRole == 'writer' ? setAsWriter(setRole, editor2Recipient, fileId) : setAsReader(setRole, editor2Recipient, fileId), console.log(`Successfully shared file ID: (${fileId}) to ${editor2Recipient} with a "${setRole}" role.`));
      });

    } catch (e) {
      console.log('Encountered an error: \n' + e)
    }

  })
}

/** Update the file permissions based on 'fileId' for users who have previously been set as 'writers'. */
function setAsReader(setRole, recipient, fileId) {
  //Get the permissions from the file.
  try {
    const pullPermissions = () => {
      return Drive.Permissions.list(fileId).permissions.filter(res => res.type == 'user' && res.role != 'owner');
    }

    const result = pullPermissions().map(permission => Drive.Permissions.update({
      role: "reader"
    }, fileId, permission.id));

    console.log(result); //For backtracking purposes of this log, this contains the number of user shared permssions existing in the file that have been updated.
  } catch {//If there are no existing permission for the file with 'reader' privilege, create a 'reader' role for the file.
    setAsWriter(setRole, recipient, fileId);
  }
}

function setAsWriter(setRole, recipient, fileId){
  Drive.Permissions.create({ role: setRole, type: "user", emailAddress: recipient }, fileId, { sendNotificationEmail: true });
}
```

### Demo

Sample sheet file:

> [image]

A sample log result:

> [image]
> *The second link (file ID: 1ZR_xvSQG_z-Ow7CKyKM82NEuGIEAYW2y) was not processed due to its blank recipient cells.*

Sample file (file ID: 1e6FO9UNX92VYuZVIzyUQ_MClLwc8tMAb):

> [image]

Comment: Thank you for your response but when I run the script, nothing happens (including modifying it to see the notifications: I then receive no notifications).
I also point out that some cells may not contain an email address.
My file: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1St90iAlwDKAJIkXSYbQIlfphjqa9Ehi79EQFFERYXBA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Got it. I have updated my script and tested it on your sample sheet. Hope it helps. Just let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: It works perfectly: thank you! One last question on this subject: I tested to share the email addresses by “commente” or “reader”, which also works. The only problem is that if, firstly, I put an address in editor, if secondly I pass it to "commenter" or "reader", it does not work, it remains in editor. How can I do ?

Comment: You're welcome. I have updated the sample script with a function named 'setAsReader', and you can pass the `fileId` as the parameter. This function uses `Drive.Permissions.update` to update the file permission from **writer** to **reader**. It utilizes the file ID and the permission ID (which will be automatically gathered inside the function) to work. You can place this function inside the `dataToBeProcessed` and replace the original `Drive.Permissions.create` method to test.

Comment: I didn't understand how I should/can use the new setAsReader function

Comment: Let me update this part.

Comment: Updated the sample script: In the `dataToBeProcessed` method, there's a `setRole` variable where you can specify whether you want the *reader* or *writer* role. This will determine whether the script adds the recipient permission as a reader/writer or updates the existing recipient with the original 'writer' permission to the 'reader' using the `setAsReader` function.

Comment: I get an error message: "Encountered an error:
GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to drive.permissions.create failed with error: Bad Request. User message: "Sorry, you do not have sharing permission."
When I look at the file I want to share, I realize that all the people it was originally shared with are deleted (it then opens read-only) -> I hypothesize that it's because I am not the owner of the file (I am working on a file that I am not the owner of; and when I create a file and run the script, it works fine)

Comment: That's right, since you're not the owner of these files, running the script will produce a type of error.